# Default, locked sorting of posting fields

Tags: admin

Is there anyway to disable custom dragging and sorting of the posting fields in admin?

From time to time, the fields gets dis-ordered, and I have to sort them back to the way I want it, witch is kinda annoying.

I want this also because I'm going to have other editors on the site, and I want a standardized order for everybody.

I also want the excerpt-field to be above the content-field.
Is all this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer the last part: "I also want the excerpt-field to be above the content-field. Is all this possible?"

The only way to move anything above the content field is via JavaScript--there are no php hooks or filters up there. It's kind of a lame workaround because you can usually see (visually) the jump as the fields reorder. But AFAIK it's the only way to do this.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

    // On DOM ready move the excerpt field above the WYSIWYG field
    if( document.getElementById('postdiv') && document.getElementById('postexcerpt') ) {
        jQuery('#postexcerpt').insertBefore('#postdiv');
    } else if( document.getElementById('postdivrich') && document.getElementById('postexcerpt') ) {
        jQuery('#postexcerpt').insertBefore('#postdivrich');
    }

});
```

Comment: Yes, that worked.